# Comments inside single quotes - PHP

Tags: php, variables, comments

How can I simply add a comment in php enclosed in single quotes:

```
// Output variable

$actions = '<a onclick="doLike('.$id.', '.$y.')" id="doLike'.$id.'">'.$state.'</a> - <a     onclick="focus_form('.$id.')">'.$LNG['comment'].'</a> - <a onclick="share('.$id.')">'.$LNG['share'].'</a> <div class="like_btn" id="like_btn'.$id.'"> '.$people.$likes.'</div>';
```

I am trying to comment out (hide) this bit of code...

```
- <a     onclick="focus_form('.$id.')">'.$LNG['comment'].'</a> -
```

But no luck with /* or //

Comment: This is pretty bad to generate html from the back-end, you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no "string comments" in PHP. You need to restructure your code so that you don't have to put comments inside strings.

For instance, you could have one tag per line:

```
$actions = '<a onclick="doLike('.$id.', '.$y.')" id="doLike'.$id.'">'.$state.'</a>';
$actions .= ' - <a     onclick="focus_form('.$id.')">'.$LNG['comment'].'</a>';
$actions .= ' - <a onclick="share('.$id.')">'.$LNG['share'].'</a>';
$actions .= '<div class="like_btn" id="like_btn'.$id.'"> '.$people.$likes.'</div>';
```

With this structure, you can comment out the line you don't like.

Answer (score 0):

You mean an HTML comment? Those look like

```
<!--a onClick..... -->
```

But note that each comment is a tag, so you have to comment even the visible text in its own tag as well

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 $actions = '<a onclick="doLike('.$id.', '.$y.')" id="doLike'.$id.'">'.$state.'</a> <!-- - <a     onclick="focus_form('.$id.')">'.$LNG['comment'].'</a> --> - <a onclick="share('.$id.')">'.$LNG['share'].'</a> <div class="like_btn" id="like_btn'.$id.'"> '.$people.$likes.'</div>';
```